# Android hide small icon on my listView

Tags: android, listview

I need hide small icon on my listView, when clicking on this item.
Unfortunately in my app when I click any item in ListView, always hiding first icon.

What I doing wrong?

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: position:" + position);

            // Get cursor
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Variables from database
            String rowId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
            String english = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("english"));
            String speak = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("speak"));


            // Set visibility THIS icon
            ImageView imageLearned = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageLearned);
            imageLearned.setVisibility(View.GONE);




            // Show varibles from database
            Snackbar.make(view, english + " [" + speak + "]", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();

        }

    });
```

Comment: attach an xml here too, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the current view:
Change

```
 ImageView imageLearned = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageLearned);
```

to

```
 ImageView imageLearned = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageLearned);
```